# get every response in Http Get

Tags: c#, .net, http, webclient

I am using WebClient to get and post requests. When i send http request to `GET` data like this:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();  
client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(requestUri), "GET");
```

I can receive data up to 1min totally. I can receive some data in 20 seconds and some other in 30 seconds and after the completion of 1min. I would like to know whenever I receive the data. Do I have any event in web client to get the bytes of data which I receive.. can any one please help me to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The [`WebClient.DownloadProgressChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadprogresschanged.aspx) event gets raised whenever one of the async methods receives data. However, there is no way to determine exactly what data has been read so it doesn't sound like this will solve your problem.

If you need full control over the request you will have to abandon `WebClient` and work directly with the lower-level [`WebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5t9y35bd.aspx) class. Specifically, you want to send a `WebRequest` in order to get a `WebResponse` and call `GetResponseStream` on it; the returned stream exposes async functionality that lets you do whatever you need. The downside is of course that you will have to orchestrate everything manually, which is going to be much more than two lines of code.

There is an example of how to do this on the MSDN docs for [`WebRequest.BeginGetResponse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.begingetresponse.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for ur answer.In the MSDN docs                              // End the Asynchronous response.
      myRequestState.response =  myWebRequest1.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult); this means are we ending the response.. but i will receive response continuous upto 1min.. could you please explain me....